# Traversing Table without IDs, storing in array for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I will confess, this question is probably your worst nightmare, but I desperately need assistance.  Any tip, trick, hint or source would be much appreciated.

Long story short, the little knowledge I have of jquery isn't getting things done...
What I am trying to do is capture the data points within the table (see below), store them in an array so that I can reformat the presentation of that data later on during page load.
The problem is is that this was written back in the day (you'll no how far back when you look at the code) and so it doesnt have any IDs or classes that are useful to me, which makes it difficult to traverse the DOM.

Any ideas on how I can target/capture the data points (by data points I mean the actual data within each table cell) using jquery?  I've tried using .html(), .text() and .each() and sometimes that works, but other times it returns actual HTML of what I am targeting...I can't seem to find a way to get just the data in an organized fashion.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

```
    //Removed code due to privacy issues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y5r1kq0e/3/

```
var item = $('tbody')[0].children;

var get = function (item) {
    var t = [];
    $.each(item, function (i) {
        var a = [];
        $.each(item[i].children, function (child) {
            a.push(this.innerText.trim())
        })
        t.push(a.join(' ').trim());
    })
    return t;
}

console.log(get(item))
```

gets you an array like this:

```
0: "Click1 Click2"
1: "Name Type Views Visitors  Clicks Clickrate  ▲ Interval Conf Lift   Clicks Clickrate ▲ Interval Conf Lift"
2: "TOTAL  632 516  8 1.55% ±0.89% - -   3 0.5814% ±0.55% - -"
3: ""
4: "Versions"
5: "V1 Challengers 301 250  2 0.8% ±0.93% - -   1 0.4% ±0.66% - -"
6: "V2 Challengers 331 266  6 2.26% ±1.5% 91% 181.95%   2 0.7519% ±0.87% 70% 87.97%"
7: ""
```

Comment: thanks, i just noticed that the 'a = []' inside the function, should be 'var a = []'..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you get cleaner data. Only get text content from inside all the `td` cells. I also filtered those rows that seems to have *data* (those with `align="right"`).

```
    $('tr[align=right] td').contents().filter(function () {
      return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).map(function () {
      return this.nodeValue;
    }).get();
```

Output:

```
["Name", "Type", "Views", "Visitors", "Clicks", "Clickrate", "▲", "Interval", "Conf", "Lift", "Clicks", "Clickrate", "▲", "Interval", "Conf", "Lift", "TOTAL", "632", "516", "8", "1.55%", "0.89%", "-", "-", "3", "0.5814%", "0.55%", "-", "-", "Versions", "Challengers", "301", "250", "2", "0.8%", "0.93%", "-", "-", "1", "0.4%", "0.66%", "-", "-", "Challengers", "331", "266", "6", "2.26%", "1.5%", "91%", "181.95%", "2", "0.7519%", "0.87%", "70%", "87.97%"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .each() in conjuction with .text().

```
var datapoints = []
    $("td").each(function(){
    var dataText = $(this).text();
        datapoints.push(dataText);
    });
```

Although after testing it here: http://jsfiddle.net/m33v82qf/ It seems you will need some way to tell the .each() function what is valid text to store in the array and what isn't. That being said it works just fine at grabbing the text from every cell on the page.

Comment: this will definitely help!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'll play around with it and see how I can take this to the next step.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you can adjust the code and add your classes to the cells that you want to extract data from then you can definitely narrow down your search criteria.